# @Spy not working when annotated on two lists

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

This is my **PersonSeviceImpl** class. Here before saving any person I want to run some validators which implements **PersonValidator**. And also I autowired **PersonStatusChangeValidator** to use in a different method.

```
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    @Autowired
    PersonDao personDao;

    @Autowired
    List<PersonStatusChangeValidator> statusChangeValidators;

    @Autowired
    List<PersonValidator> personValidators;

    @Override
    public Person save(Person person) {
        for(PersonValidator validator: personValidators){
            validator.validate(person);
        }
        personDao.save(person);
        return person;
    }
}
```

Here I am writing test to verify whether validators are called or not.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class PersonServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private PersonDao personDao;

    @Mock
    private PersonValidator personValidator;

    @Mock
    private PersonStatusChangeValidator statusChangeValidator;

    @Spy
    private List<PersonStatusChangeValidator> statusChangeValidators = new ArrayList<>();

    @Spy
    private List<PersonValidator> personValidators = new ArrayList<>();

    @InjectMocks
    private PersonServiceImpl personService;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        personValidators.add(personValidator);
        statusChangeValidators.add(statusChangeValidator);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreatePerson() throws Exception {
        personService.save(new Person());
        verify(personValidator, times(1)).validate(any(Person.class));
    }
}
```

The problem is `personValidators`, `statusChangeValidators` are null by the time I'm running test. And when there is a single `@Spy` annotation in the test, it is working fine. Need some help to know where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using spring boot?

Comment: Not an answer, but everything would be simpler is you used constructor injection. You could just use `new PersonServiceImpl(personDao, Collections.singletonList(personValidator), Collections.singletonList(statusChangeValidator))`.

Comment: Plog No, Im not using spring boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test doesn't show any mocking of statics or finals so I'm wondering why you are using `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`?

I have taken your code and successfully run it with just one change: replacing `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`.

So, unless there is some other aspect of your tests which **require** PowerMock then I'd suggest running your test case with `MockitoJUnitRunner`. If there is some aspect of your tests which require PowerMock then I'd suggest injecting the `statusChangeValidators` and `personValidators` instances with explicit constructor injection (i.e. what @JB Nizet suggested in his comment above) so that you do not have to rely on `@InjectMocks`.

FWIW, there's an [open issue against PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/807) for this inability to apply `@InjectMocks` for fields with the `@Spy` annotation.